# Text and Image in same line

Tags: html, css, image, text

I am trying to achieve something like this:
[image]

But it is turning out like this:

[image]

This is my HTML code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text 2</p>
<p align="center">
<img src="Images/image" width="150" height="150" alt="Image"/>
</p>
<p>Test 3</p>
<p>Test 4</p>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */
body
{
    background-color:#00A1B3;
}
img
{
    display:inline;
}
p
{
    display:inline-block;   
    float:left;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: give the image and the text height and width, and float all text and the image left.

Comment: To start with, don't put the image in a `p` tag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could remove the `float` property from the paragraphs, and use `display: inline-block;` *(or `inline`)*, or simply use an inline wrapper like `<span>` instead.

Also, to align vertically the inline(-block) elements, you could use `vertical-align: middle;` as follows:

```css
img {
    vertical-align: middle; }

p {
    display:inline-block; }
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsbin.com/nifadeyu/1/edit)**

For horizontal centering the inline elements, you could set the `text-align: center;` to the **parent** element:

```
.parent { text-align: center; }
```

**[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsbin.com/nifadeyu/2/edit)**.

Comment: This works but it moves the text and image to the left. How can I center it?

Comment: @AbdullahShafique I tested the Demo with different versions of Safari on different platforms. Here are the screenshots: http://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/5438f49c62de6803e47885757c41aefac8f2a981